# Create new columns based on size of groupby element in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a sample of a dataframe,

```
    id  Section A   B
0   abc foo 0.1 0.6
1   abc foo 0.2 0.3
2   abc bar 0.5 0.1
3   def foo 0.1 0.1
4   def bar 0.1 0.3
5   def bar 0.6 0.1
6   ghj foo 0.3 0.1
7   ghj foo 0.1 0.7
8   ghj bar 0.1 0.2
```

New columns `df['AA', 'BB']` to be created from the following lists.

```
A_foo = [0.1,2]
A_bar = [1,0.3]

B_foo = [0.4,0.2]
B_bar = [1.2,0.5]
```

Here is how I tried so far,

```
g = df.groupby('id')['A','B']
for i, i_d in g:
    print(i_d)
```

**

```
length of `A_foo, A_bar, B_foo and B_bar` is always greater or equal to df`

[df.Section == 'foo'] and df[df.Section == 'bar']` of any unique id.
```

Then to create `df['AA']`, for each `'foo' and 'bar'` in `df['Section']` per id, I want to take the corresponding values from `A_foo and A_bar`.

For example, in the first i_d (id = abc), `df.A` has `two 'foo' and one 'bar'` then the first three rows of `df['AA']` will look,

```
[0.1,2,1... 0.1 and 2 from A_foo and 1 from A_bar
```

then in the second `i_d(id='def')`, `df.A has one foo and two bar` so I need to add `0.1 from A_foo and 1,0.3 from A_bar`.
and now

```
df['AA'] will look [0.1,2,1,0.1,1,0.3...
```

from the last i_d, I will collect `0.1,2 from A_foo and 1 from A_bar.` 
now the complete

```
df['AA'] = [0.1,2,1,0.1,1,0.3,0.1,2,1]
```

Similarly, create `df['BB']` from `B_foo` and `B_bar`

```
df['BB'] = [0.4,0.2,1.2,0.4,1.2,0.5,0.4,0.2,1.2]
```

Here is the final df

```
    id  Section A   B   AA  BB
0   abc foo    0.1  0.6 0.1 0.4
1   abc foo    0.2  0.3 2.0 0.2
2   abc bar    0.5  0.1 1.0 1.2
3   def foo    0.1  0.1 0.1 0.4
4   def bar    0.1  0.3 1.0 1.2
5   def bar    0.6  0.1 0.3 0.5
6   ghj foo    0.3  0.1 0.1 0.4
7   ghj foo    0.1  0.7 2.0 0.2
8   ghj bar    0.1  0.2 1.0 1.2
```

Comment: And what if an `id` has more foos than the length of the foo_list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the index with `groupby` + `cumcount`, then use `np.select` to assign the values from the respective lists.

```
import numpy as np

df['idx'] = df.groupby(['id', 'Section']).cumcount()

conds = [df.Section.eq('foo'), df.Section.eq('bar')]
AA_choice = [np.array(A_foo)[df.idx], np.array(A_bar)[df.idx]]
BB_choice = [np.array(B_foo)[df.idx], np.array(B_bar)[df.idx]]

df['AA'] = np.select(conds, AA_choice, default=np.NaN)
df['BB'] = np.select(conds, BB_choice, default=np.NaN)
```

#### Output:

```
    id Section    A    B  idx   AA   BB
0  abc     foo  0.1  0.6    0  0.1  0.4
1  abc     foo  0.2  0.3    1  2.0  0.2
2  abc     bar  0.5  0.1    0  1.0  1.2
3  def     foo  0.1  0.1    0  0.1  0.4
4  def     bar  0.1  0.3    0  1.0  1.2
5  def     bar  0.6  0.1    1  0.3  0.5
6  ghj     foo  0.3  0.1    0  0.1  0.4
7  ghj     foo  0.1  0.7    1  2.0  0.2
8  ghj     bar  0.1  0.2    0  1.0  1.2
```

---

If your lists are not long enough, you will get an `IndexError`. If so, perhaps consider slicing by: `np.array(A_foo)[df.idx%len(A_foo)]`